# Theory about Rest service

Tags: php, android, database, web-services, rest

I'm confused about the REST services.

I have a database online and some php scripts.
A script is called "programma.php" and it's accessible at the URL: "www.example.org/programma.php"

This script can be invoked with a request HTTP:

- if I use the GET method, the program connects to the database and returns in  JSON format all the data in a table of the database
- if I use the POST method, the program inserts into a database table the record sent in the body of the request

The script "programma.php" is a REST service or no? Why?

I'm sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably best described as a partial implementation of a RESTful service. You also need to provide the list of acceptable transitions in the GET request so that the application can decide dynamically what it can do. It would depend a little more on the actual architecture and separation of responsibility that the system uses as well. But it is essentially a REST implementation, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
My script still does the same job depending on the request type (GET or POST).
I do not use special options. in what sense I should check GET requests?
The real URL is http://viabilita.altervista.org/rest/viabilitalia.php